# Jhipster Sorting - Json Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I am using Jhipster and trying to sort data that is unknown being sent from a postgresql database.

I could have the following columns:
ID | Data 1 | Data 2 |
or 
ID | Description | Weight|

I want to be able to sort these using jh-sort-by but because there is no "id" i can't do it. I don't know what the name will be.

Is there a way to define the data without knowing which columns will be returned?

I am using:

```js
 <tr jh-sort="vm.predicate" ascending="vm.reverse" callback="vm.transition()">
<th jh-sort-by="id"><span>ID</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
```

Comment: I am using the following


    <tr jh-sort="vm.predicate" ascending="vm.reverse" callback="vm.transition()">
    <th jh-sort-by="id"><span>ID</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>

Comment: What stops you from pre-pending an ID column if the data doesn't include one? CSS could trivially make it invisible for the sake of presentation.